# OpenGL VBO usage hints for vertices that animate rarely

Tags: opengl, vbo

Suppose I have a VBO which remains unchanged 95% of the time. But, the other 5% of the time, it's animating. I'm not sure which usage hint to give to OpenGL when calling `glBufferData`.

On the one hand, it's acting like a `GL_STATIC_DRAW` buffer 95% of the time. On the other hand, `GL_STREAM_DRAW` is recommended for animation. Should I just compromise and pass `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW`?

Or should I combine them, and call `glBufferData` with `GL_STREAM_DRAW` during animation, and then rebuffer with `GL_STATIC_DRAW` when the animation completes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only viable answer is to try stuff and see what works best for different platforms. OpenGL does not define performance, and every driver will implement these sorts of things differently. The hints are hints; they don't necessarily do anything.

In fact, AMD completely ignores your usage hints; it does what it does based on how you actually use the buffer. That's primarily because too many users of GL used them badly.